# GGX shader creation

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm trying to create a ggx shader but when I run it at BRDF Explorer the main page remains white. I'm trying to find my error but I can't.
Can anybody help me?
below is my file

analytic

```
::begin parameters

float baseColor 0.001 .2 .1

float m 0.001 0.1 1.0 

::end parameters

::begin shader

    const float PI = 3.14;


    vec3 BRDF( vec3 N, vec3 V, vec3 L, float m, float baseColor)
        {

            vec3 H = normalize(V+L);

            float dotNL = clamp(dot(N,L), 0.0, 1.0);
            float dotLH = clamp(dot(L,H), 0.0, 1.0);
            float dotNH = clamp(dot(N,H), 0.0, 1.0);

            float DotNH2 = dotNH * dotNH;
            float m2 = m * m;
            float D =  m2 / (PI * pow(dotNH * dotNH * (m2 - 1) + 1, 2.0));


            float Fresnel(float baseColor, float l, float h)
        {
            return baseColor + ( 1 - baseColor ) * pow( 1 - (dotNH), 5);
        }
            float F = Fresnel(baseColor, dotNH);


            float ggx_visib(float dotNV, float m2) 
        { 
            return 1.0/(dotNV*(1.0-m2)+m2); 
        }                       

            float g1i =ggx_visib(m, dotLH);
            float g1o =ggx_visib(m, dotNV);
            float G = g1i * g1o;



        return D * G * F * (1.0 / (4.0 * dotNL * dotNV));


        }

::end shader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 function declarations in the middle of the function `BRDF`. This is not allowed. In GLSL a function definition has to be global.

See [GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6; 6.1. Function Definitions
; page 122](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> As indicated by the grammar above, a valid shader is a sequence of global declarations and function definitions.

Move the declarations of `Fresnel` and `ggx_visib` before the declaration of `BRDF` to solve your issue.

The major issue is, that the [BRDF explorer](https://www.disneyanimation.com/technology/brdf.html) requires the keyword `analytic` at the begin of the file, to identify the file as a light model.

After the keyword is add add the file reloaded, the application will trace error cause by your GLSL code.

Fixing the errors results in the following code:

```
analytic

::begin parameters

float baseColor 0.001 .2 .1

float m 0.001 0.1 1.0

::end parameters

::begin shader

const float PI = 3.14;

float Fresnel(float baseColor, float l, float h)
{
    return baseColor + ( 1 - baseColor ) * pow( 1 - (h), 5);
}

float ggx_visib(float dotNV, float m2) 
{ 
    return 1.0/(dotNV*(1.0-m2)+m2); 
} 

vec3 BRDF( vec3 N, vec3 V, vec3 L, vec3 X, vec3 Y)
{
    vec3 H = normalize(V+L);

    float dotNL = clamp(dot(N,L), 0.0, 1.0);
    float dotLH = clamp(dot(L,H), 0.0, 1.0);
    float dotNH = clamp(dot(N,H), 0.0, 1.0);

    float DotNH2 = dotNH * dotNH;
    float m2 = m * m;
    float D =  m2 / (PI * pow(dotNH * dotNH * (m2 - 1) + 1, 2.0));

    float F = Fresnel(baseColor, dotNL, dotNH);

    float g1i =ggx_visib(m, dotLH);
    float g1o =ggx_visib(m, dotNH);
    float G = g1i * g1o;

    float k = D * G * F * (1.0 / (4.0 * dotNL * dotNH));
    return vec3(k);
}
::end shader
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.   I moved the declarations of Fresnel and ggx_visib before the declaration of BRDF as you mention my code now is excacly as  you have edit it. However the I opened it on BRDF explorer I still get the same blanc page. It doesn't show nor a ball nor some kind of light.  I don't know what I;m doing wrong here

Comment: Hello, No it doesn't I modified the code to be Fresnel - return baseColor + ( 1 - baseColor ) * pow( 1 - (h), 5); but I don't get any result.

Comment: When I opened it to BRDF explorer the page stay empty. It doesn't show anything

Comment: From https://www.disneyanimation.com/technology/brdf.html I've dowloaded the win32binary. So I created my file at notepad and I tried to run it. I guess I'm doing something ridiculously wrong, but honestly I don't know what..

Comment: I guess I'm not do it correclty. So what I do is,  after unziping the downloaded file I run  the BRDF.exe which open the program. From there I go file menu-> open BRDF. If I choose one of the existing brdf file the screen changes it has the ball and the light effect. However I choose the file I created nothing changes it is like the program doesn't even read it... Do I need to do something diffrent??

Comment: Hello, thank you for all the help you giving me. I dit the modification you told me but I still don't get result . On brdf.exe window it appears the message BRDF Version 1.0.0
opening ./probes/beach.penv
Unrecognised OpenGL version

Comment: @user3052811 I downloaded the application and made your code run. The major issue is that the keyword `analytic` at the begin of the .brdf file was missing in your code. The code in my answer is the final code with all GLSL compile errors fixed.

Comment: Long story short, i think the Function BRDF has five parameters contaning vec3

[source](https://github.com/wdas/brdf/blob/5b2cd46f38a06e47207fa7229b72d37beb945019/src/brdf/BRDFBase.cpp#L407)
passing floats in that looks wrong to me. I have also the OpenGL Unrecognised version (warning), but i can edit and save files.

Comment: @Nabr The `BRDF` function in the answer has 5  `vec3`. The other functions are sub functions. The code in the question finally works, as I mentioned in the comment above. copy/past and try

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late answer. Thank you very much for your help I run the program and it is working now. Thank you again !