# How to fix Unrecognised OpenGL version in my shader?

Tags: glsl, shader

I've created a brdf file but then I try to open it in BRDF explorer 
in the brdf.exe it appears the following message.

> BRDF Version 1.0.0
>   opening ./probes/beach.penv
>   Unrecognised OpenGL version

My code had some problems but with help from team stackoverflow I fixed.
however there is still one problem.
Can anyone advise how to fix this?

this is my code

analytic

```
::begin parameters

float baseColor 0.001 .2 .1

float m 0.001 0.1 1.0

::end parameters

::begin shader

const float PI = 3.14;

    float Fresnel(float baseColor, float l, float h)
    {
        return baseColor + ( 1 - baseColor ) * pow( 1 - (h), 5);
    }

    float ggx_visib(float dotNV, float m2) 
    { 
        return 1.0/(dotNV*(1.0-m2)+m2); 
    }

    vec3 BRDF( vec3 N, vec3 V, vec3 L, float m, float baseColor)
    {
        vec3 H = normalize(V+L);

        float dotNL = clamp(dot(N,L), 0.0, 1.0);
        float dotLH = clamp(dot(L,H), 0.0, 1.0);
        float dotNH = clamp(dot(N,H), 0.0, 1.0);

        float DotNH2 = dotNH * dotNH;
        float m2 = m * m;
        float D =  m2 / (PI * pow(dotNH * dotNH * (m2 - 1) + 1, 2.0));


        float F = Fresnel(baseColor, dotNH);

        float g1o =ggx_visib(m, dotNH);
        float g1o =ggx_visib(m, dotNV);
        float G = g1i * g1o;



    D * G * F * (1.0 / (4.0 * dotNL * dotNH));


    }
::end shader
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GGX shader creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825287/ggx-shader-creation)

Comment: The function `Fresnel` has 3 parameter, but you only pass 2. Signature: `float Fresnel(float baseColor, float l, float h)`; Call: `float F = Fresnel(baseColor, dotNH);` Futher the `return` statement is missing in the function `BRDF`

Comment: Try to add a version information at the top of your shader code e.g. `#version 150`. See [Core Language (GLSL) - Version](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version)

Comment: hello, I want to thank you for efford in helping me. It didn't find a solution but I really appreciate your help and correction you provided me.